# Instagram : Liking a photo on an external site

Tags: javascript, ajax, instagram-api

So I'm trying to understand the Instagram API and I'm a bit lost.

I have a site where I will be displaying one image from my Instagram and will have a LIKE button.

From what I can gather all I need is my Client ID and then I can send a post request via AJAX to like the photo on Instagram. But first I need to authenticate the user first? This is where I'm stumped. Is there a tutorial that can walk me through this? So when the user clicks on LIKE it pops up a window to authenticate them and then it likes the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the [Instagram API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and also take a look at the Instagram Javascript SDK they have on Github: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-javascript-sdk

Alternatively, there is another Instagram JS SDK you could use, written by Bryantchan - https://github.com/bryantchan/Instagram-JS-SDK

An example from Bryan's SDK on authentication is below:

```
var IG = new Instagram();

var param = {
    client_id    : YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri : YOUR_REDIRECT_URI,
    scope        : YOUR_SCOPE,
    response_type: 'token'
}

IG.auth( param ); //then will go to the authorize page

//handle the fn token
var token = IG.getToken();

//you need to set token before you use it
IG.setOptions( {
    token: token
} );

//or without using token 
IG.setOptions({
    client_id: your_client_id
})

//you code...
```

Comment: Ah I think that will help immensely. Checking it out.